# Hibernate EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find xxx

Tags: hibernate

I have entity with map field inside it.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dictionaries")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Dictionary {

    .........         

    @ElementCollection
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKeyColumn(name="word_id")
    @Column(name="translation ")
    @CollectionTable(name="dict_word_translate", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="dict_id"))
    private Map<Translation, Word> attributes = new HashMap();

    .........
}
```

**Translation:**

```
@Entity
public class Translation {

     @Id
     private String value;

    public Translation() {}

    public Translation(String translation) {
        this.value = translation;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
         this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Word:**

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "Word.retrivetFirst",
    query = "from Word u where u.value = ?1")
public class Word {

    @Id
    private String value;

    public Word() {}

    public Word(String word) {
        this.value = word;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And I have method in dao to save Dictionary:

```
public Dictionary addWordToDictionary(int id, Word word, Translation translation) {
    Dictionary dict = getDictionary(id);
    dict.getAttributes().put(translation, word);
    repository.save(dict);
    return dict;
}
```

When I try to call this method I received:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find allig.englishtrainer.dao.translation.Translation with id
```

How I can save Dictionary correctly with automatically saving Translation and Word entities?

**UPDATE**

I find out a way hot to make it works by call before saving dictionary saving translation.

```
translationRepository.save(translation);
```

But, maybe, Hibernate has some Annotation to do it automatically?

Comment: General: Why don't you just take strings as words and translations? It is a lack of encapsulation when you expose the map in the dictionary.

Comment: The problem most probably is that your dictionary doesn't exits. What do you pass as id? Where does it come from? Usually there is no id known anywhere until you created an entity.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger id is okey. Program fails at this 
repository.save(dict);
And I have created Word and Translation with already set value field.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I don't know how to make ideal design for this program, so I have separate question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755925/hibernate-entity-mapping-understanding